# Is { a^nb^na^n} a context-sensitive language?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

The language $L_1 = \{ a^nb^nc^n \}$ is often given as an example of a context-sensitive language.

I am wondering if the language $L_2 = \{ a^nb^na^n \}$ belongs also to the same category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar:

> $S\to aS'Ba\mid aba \mid\varepsilon$
>
> $S'\to aS'Ba\mid aba$ (so that only the start symbol can generate the empty word)
>
> $aB \to Ba$ (to move the inner $a$'s to the right)
>
> $bB \to bb$ (to transform all $B$'s into $b$'s)

is a noncontracting grammar generating the language $\{a^nb^na^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$. That means the language is context-sensitive.

Beware that the previous grammar is not context-sensitive (the problematic rule is $aB\to Ba$).

If you want a context-sensitive grammar, it is a bit more complicated. Something like this should work:

> $S\to aS'BA\mid aba \mid \varepsilon$
>
> $S' \to aS'BA\mid abA$
>
> $AB\to XB$
>
> $XB \to XY$
>
> $XY\to BY$
>
> $BY \to BA$
>
> $bB\to bb$
>
> $A \to a$